# How to assign relation object to instance variable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing a loop with switch case , instead of querying database three time , I am getting all lookup in one query and looping with conditions to assign to different instance variable ( which I will use in simple form as collections) . I am not sure how to append active record relations to instance variable, pls help me.

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @question = Question.new
    @question_lookups = Lookup.where({:look_up_for => "question"})

    @question_lookups.each do |lk|
        case lk.look_up_type
            when 'mode'
                @question_mode = lk #How can i do this here..?
            when 'status'
                @question_status = lk
            else
                @question_type = lk
        end
    end
    session[:lk] = @question_mode

    # @question_mode = Lookup.where({:look_up_for => "question", :look_up_type => "mode"})
    # @question_status = Lookup.where({:look_up_for => "question", :look_up_type => "status"})
    # @question_type = Lookup.where({:look_up_for => "question", :look_up_type => "type"})
end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert question_mode and so on into arrays and push lk to it

```
@question_mode, @question_status, @question_type = []
@question_lookups.each do |lk|
    case lk.look_up_type
        when 'mode'
            @question_mode << lk #How can i do this here..?
        when 'status'
            @question_status << lk
        else
            @question_type << lk
    end
end
```

Comment: declaration should be one by one like this : 
`
@question_status = []
@question_mode = []
@question_type = []
`

Comment: what do you mean with "should be"? In terms of code style? Writing it like this is a common Ruby paradigm ...